# $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ convolution group $\Rightarrow$ $(P_t)_{t>0}$ continuous convolution group

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ a convolution semigroup, i.e. a family of probability measures with the property $\forall s,t\ge 0: P_t\ast P_s=P_{t+s}$.

I want to show that $P_t\rightarrow \delta_0$ for $t\rightarrow 0$ with respect to weak convergence. Suppose  $P_t\rightarrow Q\ne\delta_0$ for $t\rightarrow 0$. It follows

$$ P_{t}=P_{t/2}\ast P_{t/2}\rightarrow Q\ast Q$$

for $t\rightarrow 0$. Therefore $Q\ast Q =Q$. Now this is only true for $\delta_0$, which contradicts the assumption. Is this proof right?

Comment: Measures on what space?  If on a non trivial  compact abelian group with Haar measure $H$, then , $P_t=H$ for all $t$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I think on $(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$, where $E$ is a polish space and $\mathcal{B}(E)$ it's borel-$\sigma$-algebra. Or some $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Would that make any difference?

Comment: I mean, what is "convolution" in this context?

Comment: Oh, that should be $(\mu \ast \nu) (B):=\int \int 1_B(x+y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)$.

Comment: But I think out of this definition, one should see, that only $\delta_0$ can be the neutral element. $\int \int 1_B(x+y)\mu(dx)\nu(dy)= \int 1_B(x)\mu(dx)$ can only be true, if $y=0$, and $\nu(E)=1$?

Comment: What is the range of integration, what does "+" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about probability measures on the reals, and convolution with respect to $(\mathbb R, +)$, the answer is No.  A convolution semigroup need not be continuous anywhere.

Let $f$ be any discontinuous solution of Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$  (these are discontinuous everywhere, and unbounded in every neighborhood) and let $P_t=\delta_{f(t)}$ be the point mass concentrated at $f(t)$.  Then the convolution property $P_t*P_s=P_{s+t}$  is satisfied, but the map $t\mapsto P_t$ is not weak* continuous.  For if it were, since $x\mapsto \tanh(x)$ is continuous and bounded,  the function $t\mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} \tanh( x)P_t(dx) = \tanh(f(t)) $ would have to be continuous.  Which it is not, not even at $t=0$.

A flaw in your argument is assuming that the only way $P_t\to\delta_0$ can fail is for $P_t\to Q$ for some $Q\ne \delta_0$.